# How do I check if an insert was successful with MySQLdb in Python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have this code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(("insert into new_files (videos_id, filename, "
                "is_processing) values (%s,%s,1)"), (id, filename))
logging.warn("%d", cursor.rowcount)
if (cursor.rowcount == 1):
    logging.info("inserted values %d, %s", id, filename)
else:
    logging.warn("failed to insert values %d, %s", id, filename)
cursor.close()
```

Fun as it is, `cursor.rowcount` is *always* one, even though i updated my database to make the videos_id a unique key. That is, the  insert fails because in my tests the same `videos_id` is going to appear (and when I check the database, nothing was inserted).
But for whatever reason, the `rowcount` is always 1 - even the `logging.warn` I have spits out a `rowcount` of 1.

So, the question:
Can I use `rowcount` to work out if an insert went fine? If so, what am I (presumably) doing wrong?
otherwise, how do i check if an insert went fine?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your code does not commit after the modifications (your modifications are rolled back). That is, you should add the following line after `cursor.execute`:

```
conn.commit()
```

Failed insert will throw `MySQLdb.IntegrityError`, so you should be ready to catch it.

Thus, your code should look something like:

```
sql_insert = """insert into new_files (videos_id, filename, is_processing)
values (%s,%s,1)"""

cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    affected_count = cursor.execute(sql_insert, (id, filename))
    conn.commit()
    logging.warn("%d", affected_count)
    logging.info("inserted values %d, %s", id, filename)
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    logging.warn("failed to insert values %d, %s", id, filename)
finally:
   cursor.close()
```

Comment: Question. What if your inserting 500 records at a time before committing (either by one long query or multiple discrete inserts)? i.e. I'm only committing every 500 records; if one of those records fails how do I print only that one record and continue inserting the others.

Comment: @user3656612 it depends on why they fail. If the problem is with breaking some constraints, you might use INSERT IGNORE or INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. If it is a connection error, you can't do anything. If it is a syntax error - you should consider fixing bugs in your application.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, but here's an important note:

It is also possible for execute() to fail silently if you don't commit after the call. Namely, MyISAM tables don't require the commit, but InnoDB ones do.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a try/catch block instead of looking at rowcount.
If it catches an exception then there is a problem; otherwise, no problem.

Comment: I'm kinda new to python (and mysqldb), any chance you could splurge on an example - ie what exception do i catch in the try catch block?

Answer (score 0):

Store the insert statement in the string and print it after. If an exception occurs the statement won't print.

```
sql_insert = """insert into new_files (videos_id, filename, is_processing)
values (%s,%s,1)"""
cur.execute(sql_insert)
print('Executed:', sql_insert)
```