# Python | MySQLdb -> I cant insert

Tags: python, database, insert, mysql-python

I have an odd problem.
There are two databases. One has all products in it for an online shop. The other one has the online-shop software on it and only the active products.

I want to take the values from db1, change some values in python and insert into db2.

```
db1.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")
for product in db1.fetchall():
    # ...
    db2.execute("INSERT INTO table2 ...")
    print "Check: " + str(db2.countrow)
```

So I can get the values via select, even selecting from db2 is no problem. My check always gives me 1 BUT there are no new rows in table2. The autoincrement value grows but the there is no data.
And I dont even get an error like "couldnt insert"
So does anybody has an idea what could be wrong? (if i do an insert manually via phpmyadmin it works... and if i just take the sql from my script and do it manually the sql-statements work aswell)

EDIT: Found the answer here [How do I check if an insert was successful with MySQLdb in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014233/python-and-mysqldb-how-do-i-check-if-an-insert-was-successful)

Is there a way to make these executes without committing everytime?
I have a wrapper around the mysqldb and it works perfectly for me, changing the behaviour with commit I need to make some big changes.

EDIT2: ok i found out that db1 is MyISAM (which would work without commiting) and db2 is InnoDB (which actually seems only to work with commiting) I guess I have to change db2 to MyISAM aswell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `db2.commit()` after the inserts if you're using InnoDB.

> Starting with 1.2.0, MySQLdb disables autocommit by default, as
>   required by the DB-API standard (PEP-249). If you are using InnoDB
>   tables or some other type of transactional table type, you'll need to
>   do connection.commit() before closing the connection, or else none of
>   your changes will be written to the database.

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away

Comment: thanks just found this out myself in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014233/python-and-mysqldb-how-do-i-check-if-an-insert-was-successful

Comment: I never had the problem before. it actually really annoys me. The databases arent even innodb they are myisam. is there no way to make it like it was before? ^^

Comment: @xMRW there should be a connection setting parameter that sets autocommit to true. Have a care though, as transactions are an important part of db integrity.

Comment: Yes, it's a keyword parameter when opening the connection: `autocommit=True`.