# How to check whether query have inserted data or not in Python

Tags: python, django

I am using raw sql queries for inserting the data into DB. The insertion is working right, Now I want to perform some checks on this insert query e.g. If the query has inserted the data or not
suppose I have insert query like

```
cursor.execute("some insert query" )
```

Now I want to know whether  `cursor.execute` has inserted the row then show me some text like **success** and if it fails to insert for some **reason** then show me text like **error** and also if the row is already inserted then show, **row already exist**.

But I don't know how to perform these checks on `cursor.execute`.

**edit**

```
for i in range(numrows):
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                if row[6]==1:
                        arr["user_id"]=row[0]
                        arr["email"]=row[1]
                        arr["style_quiz_score"]=row[2]
                        arr["style_quiz_answer"]=row[3]
                        arr["date_joined"]=row[4]
                        arr["is_active"]=row[5]
                        arr['firstname'] = row[7]

                        arr["username"]=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '_', arr["email"])
                elif row[6]==2:
                        arr['lastname'] = row[7]
        cursor1.execute("insert into auth_user(id,username,first_name,last_name,email,password,is_staff,is_active,is_superuser,date_joined,last_login)  values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,'NULL',0,%s,0,%s,0)",[arr["user_id"],arr["username"],arr['firstname'],arr['lastname'],arr["email"],arr["is_active"],arr["date_joined"]])
```

when i am executing  `cursor1.execute` outside forloop than it insert the last entry , but if i execute it in inside forloop than it gives error and nothing will be inserted

Comment: Maybe this SO question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014233/python-and-mysqldb-how-do-i-check-if-an-insert-was-successful

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

Comment: I suggest you learn how to do this properly; if you're using Django then you shouldn't be using raw SQL.  Django has a nice "models" layer that you should be using.  See the docs on the Django web site.

Comment: I suggest not using raw SQL for that either, Django's ORM is great for what you're trying to do. But just out of curiosity: what error do you get when inserting in the for loop? Also, I don't see any calls to `transaction.commit_unless_managed` in your code. Using that may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Django (you're not specific about it in your question, but you're using the django tag), you need to do `transaction.commit_unless_managed()` (`from django.db import transaction`) after issuing the insert query with `cursor.execute`.

You can check for exceptions when calling `commit_unless_managed` to see if the insert went well or not:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction, DatabaseError, IntegrityError

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("some insert query" )

try:
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()
except DatabaseError, IntegrityError:
    print 'error'
else:
    print 'success'
```